# Convert NSString without numbers into float

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSString which doesn't necessarily contain numbers, for example it could say "Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz". I want to change this into a float value, that would be representative of this. I don't have a required formula, just some consistent way of changing this into a number value, that I can put into a randomizer.

Comment: What float value does arbitrary text equate to? You want to use the ascii code of each character?

Comment: Representative of this? What do you mean?

Comment: @Wain ascii code would be fine. @larme I mean it needs to specifically not be random. I need to get the same output every time, but for it to also not just be `0.00000`.

Comment: You want to extract numbers if they will be there and convert it in float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the solution i'm looking for might be:

```
[string hash];
```

If if I'm particularly set on a float:

```
[[string hash] floatValue];
```

Comment: `-hash` method return a `NSUInteger`, not a `NSNumber` instance or so,  so no method `-floatValue` available.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the Java way of hashing strings, except using a `float` instead of `int`:

```
- (float)hashOfString:(NSString *str) {
    float hash = 7.0f;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [str length]; i++)
        hash *= (float)[str characterAtIndex:i];
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just call [str hash] and be done with it?

Comment: Yeah that would work too :)